# How do I insert content after new page (automatically generated) or forced page break with dompdf using Twig?

Tags: dompdf

I have created a PDF template that consists simply on a table with a header and multiple rows using Twig to create a PDF through dompdf library.

My problem is that I'm required to insert always another content, specifically a table, after each page with the purpose of having this another table always on the back page when doing duplex printing (in other words, at the end there should be an even number of pages, with the odd ones corresponding to the first table and the even ones corresponding to the inserted table). Do you know if there is a way to achieve this using dompfd or another PDF generation library compatible with Symfony/Twig?

**Update**: After thinking about other approaches to solve the problem, finally I discovered a library named [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk), that allowed me to create the PDF that I wanted by separating each table into separated PDF's (with dompdf) and then merging both files with the function named "shuffle" (from pdftk), that inserts one page of the first PDF and then one page of the second PDF and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Dompdf can handle the CSS property [`page-break-*`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/):

```
.page_break {
    page-break-after:always;
}
```

```html
<h1>Page 1</h1>
...
...
<div class="page_break"></div>
<h1>Page 2</h1>
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you! But the problem in my case is not exactly with the forced page breaks, but with the automatically generated when all the rows don't fit in one page because I don't know in first place if there is a way to handle that page breaks and in second place if I can insert the second table without breaking the flow of the first one.

Comment: When I had this in the past I had to verify manually how many rows fit on one page, if the number of rows exceed the max. amount of rows on a table I had to manually break up the table in two (or more) and add a pagebreak in between

Comment: That's a very good idea. Considering this maybe I have more options trying to include the second table, thanks again.